# Publishing Alteryx data extract to Tableau server giving Duplicate table error

Tags: tableau-api, alteryx

I am using Publish to Tableau server plugin in the Alteryx Designer.

I have a workflow which publish 2 output reports with the same name on 2 different site of the same tableau server.

I am using Alteryx Designer version(10.6.8.178.50). The same version is installed on two machines. On machine A it's publishing report without error. On machine B it's publishing report but giving error with message:'Duplicate table error'.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: To clarify, each machine is publishing a different report?

Comment: On both machine same workflow is copied. it just that input data source size differs. everything else is same.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is that 'Overwrite' is selected on the output on the machine with the error.

Comment: thanks for ur input. I have selected 'Overwrite' option only. apart from this behavior differs in two different  machines having same version installed.